# Возможна ли генерация UUID в прикрепляемом XML-файле HTTP Request в Jmeter?

Tags: soap, jmeter, uuid

Для тестирования SOAP требуется подставлять в каждый новый запрос случайный UUID. Я пробовала сделать это через `{_UUID}` и отправлять тело запроса через `Body Data` в HTTP Request, но в таком случае запрос не проходит и падает с ответом `500 (Invalid Security Header)`. На текущий момент выбрала способ прикрепления XML, но так как id не меняется, запросы не приходят на стенд, но и не падают с ошибкой.
Можно ли как-то генерировать UUID непосредственно в приложенном файле?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы читаете файл функцией типа [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) то никакие функции и переменные внутри этого файла не обрабатываются.

Вам нужно дополнительно завернуть это в функцию [__eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval)

Например, если у вас что-то вроде `${__FileToString(test.xml,,)}` нужно это заменить на `${__eval(${__FileToString(test.xml,,)})}`

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чуть больше информации о том, что такое функции и переменные JMeter: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)

Comment: Попробую данный вариант, спасибо!